# FFMPEG - Why doesn't this ffmpeg converted video play on LG TV while another does?

Tags: macos, ffmpeg, video-conversion, video-encoding

I have two files created from same big mp4 file. One (A.mp4) plays fine on my LG TV while the TV complains about the other (B.mp4). A.mp4 is of 5 seconds while B.mp4 is of 10 minutes.

The first one was created with this ffmpeg command:

```
ffmpeg -t 00:00:05  -i parent.mp4  -c:v h264 A.mp4
```

When I used this command to convert the whole thing (~ 2 and half hours), the resulting file didn't run on the tv. Only thing I could see different compared to A.mp4 was the large bit rate of ~22000 kbps. Thinking I had found the problem, I ran the ffmpeg but restricted the bit rate to that of A.mp4. (Didn't use the codec setting since the parent is also h.264 encoded).

```
ffmpeg -i parent.mp4 -t 00:10:00 -b:v 8540k B.mp4
```

But this file didn't play on the TV. Both play fine on my Mac.

Here is the diff report between the ffprobe output on two files:

```
1c1
< Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'A.mp4':
---
> Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'B.mp4':
7,8c7,8
<   Duration: 00:00:05.02, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 8653 kb/s
<     Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 8540 kb/s, 59.94 fps, 59.94 tbr, 60k tbn, 119.88 tbc (default)
---
>   Duration: 00:10:00.02, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 8642 kb/s
>     Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 8501 kb/s, 59.94 fps, 59.94 tbr, 60k tbn, 119.88 tbc (default)
11c11
<     Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 127 kb/s (default)
---
>     Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)
```

I would like to find right ffmpeg settings to convert the entire parent file so that it will play on the LG TV. Appreciate any ideas.

Update:
Ran the command suggested by @llogan and here is the log:

```
ffmpeg -i A.mp4  -map 0 -c copy B.mp4
ffmpeg version 4.1.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
 Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'A.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.20.100
  Duration: 00:00:05.02, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 8653 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 8540 kb/s, 59.94 fps, 59.94 tbr, 60k tbn, 119.88 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 127 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
Output #0, mp4, to 'B.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.20.100
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=2-31, 8540 kb/s, 59.94 fps, 59.94 tbr, 60k tbn, 60k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 127 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (copy)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame=  300 fps=0.0 q=-1.0 Lsize=    5305kB time=00:00:04.99 bitrate=8705.9kbits/s speed=8.78x
video:5218kB audio:78kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.172889%
```

Comment: Test `ffmpeg -i A.mp4 -map 0 -c copy B.mp4`. Does `B.mp4` work? If not, then show the **complete** log from this command.

Comment: Ok. Think I solved it. It was the high fps that LG tv didn't like. It played the file converted with -r 30 flag.

Comment: @llogan I did what you said although didn't clearly understand it. File created with this command worked. But, isn't it because its the same as A.mp4? Anyways here is the log:

Comment: I assumed you meant that `A.mp4` worked, but your file named `B.mp4` did not. Your diff did not show any obvious difference between them. So if `A.mp4` already worked I wanted you to try re-muxing it to see if the problem is at the muxing level and not the stream level.

Comment: Yes, that assumption is right. And, didn't think of that. Thanks for your help.